# ngx gallery action - on click lost the context

Tags: angular, onclick, attachment, image-gallery

I have something like this:

```
let galleryAction = <NgxGalleryAction>{
         icon: this.actionButton,
         onClick: this.actionButtonClicked
};
```

And my method actionButtonClicked is simple, I have to emit my attachment clicked to the parent component:

```
actionButtonClicked(event, i) {
        let attachment = this.galleryImages.attachments[i];
        this.galleryActionEmitter.emit(attachment);
    }
```

Unfortunatly "this" is not my component context, but rather:
[image]

Obviously this code is not working because the "galleryActionEmitter" variable is not found.

I had tried to assign "this" to a global variable but that solution causes others problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the solution was pretty simple.
It was necessary to bind "this" to the method callback before assign, like this:

```
this.actionButtonClicked = this.actionButtonClicked.bind(this);

let galleryAction = <NgxGalleryAction>{
         icon: this.actionButton,
         onClick: this.actionButtonClicked
};
```

and everything works!